# Find $E[N^2 | N > 2]$ for a frequency distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, frequency-severity

N has probability mass function: $p_o = p_1 =0$ and $p_k = \frac{1}{(e^1-2)k!}$ for $k=2,3,4,...$ I Solved for the pgf of N and got $G(t) = \frac{e^t}{e^1-2}$

How do I calculate $E[N^2 | N>2]$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty 1/(e^1k!) = 1-2e^{-1} \approx  0.26424$ so that would not be a probability mass function

Comment: What I did was $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{c}{k!} = 1$ which using exp series gave $ce^1=1$ Did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: You need to decide whether your sum starts with $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$.  Though it does not really matter if you are conditioning on $N \gt 2$

Comment: Did I get the pmf wrong? The c value I got was 1/e

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N^2 | N > 2] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 Pr(N=n|N>2) \\
&= \frac1{1-P(N\le 2)}\sum_{n=3}^\infty n^2\cdot \frac{1}{(e-2)n!} \\
&=\frac1{1-\frac1{2(e-2)}}\sum_{n=3}^\infty n\cdot \frac{1}{(e-2)(n-1)!} \\
&= \frac1{1-\frac1{2(e-2)}}\sum_{n=3}^\infty (n-1+1)\cdot \frac{1}{(e-2)(n-1)!} \\
&=\frac{2}{2(e-2)-1} \left(\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-2)!}  + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \right)
\end{align}

I am leaving the last step for you to simplify.